# Excel is giving wrong Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have three cells with values

```
F5 = 85647846.76
G5 = -1229847.66
H5 = 84417999.1
```

In "Format Cells" the decimal places is kept as 30.

But in a new column when I do =SUM(F5 +G5 -H5) , instead of 0 I get "1.49011611938477E-08" . Is there any setting that I need to do to get the Sum as 0?

Comment: You will find [this article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) helpful :-)

Comment: I get zero as well.  F5 + G5 = H5. Unless we are talking about extreme decimal points? But that would not show up with the figures you have supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using
=sum(f5+g5-h5)

replace it with
=f5+G5-H5

Worked for me...

[image]